Correct alias syntax in GHDL
I'm implementing my first RISC-V processor in VHDL-2008. For simulation I'm using GHDL (version 5.0). The processor structure looks like this:
my_implementation
|
|___test.vhd                 - riscpol_tb entity
|___design.vhd               - riscpol entity
|
|___core                     - core entity
|   |___alu_design.vhd
|   .
|   .
|   .
|   |___reg_file_design.vhd  - reg_file entity

While executing instructions, I want to verify the General-Purpose Register. So I created an alias in the test:
alias spy_gpr is <<signal .riscpol_tb.inst_riscpol.inst_core.inst_reg_file.gpr: t_gpr >>;

Where gpr: t_gpr is
type t_gpr is array(0 to 31) of std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal gpr : t_gpr;

I want to use the alias in the test in this way:
if (spy_gpr(3) /= 32x"fffffffe") then
   report "ERROR: addi  x3,  x0,   -2    # x3 = 0xfffffffe";
end if;

Unfortunately, GHDL returns an error:
ghdl -e -frelaxed --syn-binding --std=08 --work=riscpol_lib riscpol_tb
../../riscpol_tb.vhd:74:80:error: external name and object have different type
    alias spy_gpr is <<signal .riscpol_tb.inst_riscpol.inst_core.inst_reg_file.gpr: t_gpr >>;
                                                                               ^
make: *** [Makefile:35: run_test_and_generate_waves] Error 1

I have a question, how can I create an alias to GPR in such a project structure?
P.S. In ModelSim it works, but I want to use GHDL.

You dont say where t_gpr is declared - is it in the same place as the alias? Ideally post an MCVE. If the type declaration is not in a package that is visible internally to the DUT and also the testbench, you have re-declared the type and hence they are not the same as each other and hence you cannot declare an alias to the object.

Provide a [mcve]. Each declaration in VHDL is unique. Two type declarations with the same identifier are two different types. This is why we use packages , making declarations found in a package declaration visible by use clause. See IEEE Std 1076-2008 8.7 External names "...Moreover, it is an error if the base type of the object denoted by an external name is not the same as the base type of the type mark in the subtype indication of the external name." 4th para from the end (not counting notes).

@user16145658 It's in the question: GHDL version 5.0.

The output of ghdl --version provides more information. The latest actually released version is 4.1.0 and anything with 5. in it is a development release where the r number or commit number and back end type are very important in any technical discussion.

I solved the problem. type t_gpr is array(0 to 31) of std_logic_vector(31 downto 0); should be declared in the one package, which is available for the test (test.vhd) and the register file (reg_file_design.vhd). Until now, type t_gpr is array(0 to 31) of std_logic_vector(31 downto 0); was declared in two places, in the register file and the test. I thought it is the same type, but it isn't.
Thank you for your answers, they helped me a lot.

See [ask]. Without resorting to your answer the lack of a minimal reproducible example prevents future readers from determining your problem or evaluating potential answers, incidentally leaving you the only one understanding the problem and capable of answering. Comments are frangible and can be easily removed.
